# Offset with Waypoint.Inview()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm using something like this to capture scroll events on a web page:

```
var myblock = new Waypoint.Inview({
    element: $('#block')[0],
    entered: function(direction) {
     //do stuff
    },
    exited: function(direction) {
      if(direction === "down") {
       // do other stuff
      }
    }
  });
```

The problem is that I have a sticky menu with a height of 100px at the top, and that I need Waypoint to trigger when some `<div id="block">` touches that menu. Right now, the Waypoint code is triggered when `<div id="block">` reaches the top of the viewport, where part of the `div` is already under the menu.

I tried adding the `offset` parameter but I don't see any changes

```
var myblock = new Waypoint.Inview({
    element: $('#block')[0],
    entered: function(direction) {
     //do stuff
    },
    exited: function(direction) {
      if(direction == "down") {
       // do other stuff
      }
    },
    offset: 100 // ADDED, NOTHING CHANGED
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. There is currently no support for offsets with the Inview shortcut. At this time you will have to write it using a couple regular Waypoints.

Comment: Hey Caleb, thanks for replying. Okay, I'm rewriting the code without using Inview.